# I can't add a column to a table with data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing this:

create:

```
php artisan make:migration add_total_invoice --table=invoices
```

Code:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->double('total')->after('type');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('total');
    });
}
```

```
php artisan migrate
```

The migration runs without problems, but I am going to check the table and the column is not added, if I create a new migration and put a total to the new column, it says that the column already exists, what error is occurring?

Comment: Try again with nullable(): `$table->double('total')->nullable()->after('type');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the database table and delete the previous total column in the table and again go to the migration table and delete the last migration. then run `php artisan migrate` again